# Cut a triangle into a polygon that does not cross a line segment

Tags: geometry

Here's a crude example: [image: example]

The red line is the line segment. The blue triangle is the triangle. The green polygon is the new polygon cut from the triangle which does not intersect the line segment.

And another one:

[image: example 2]

What would be the algorithm to determine how to cut the triangle?

Answer (score 1):

For each segment, calculate intersection point.(return null if nothing found)

Then for each segment, keep the segment without intersection point, then add the 2 previously calculated intersection points.

If you define your triangle with vectors it is quite easy to implement, let's say your triangle is ABC (C the point at the top), your triangle have three vectors :

AB, BC and CA.
I will call the two intersection points C2 and C3 (on first figure you will have only one intersection point).

AB has no intersection point->keep AB
BC has an intersection point (C2) -> BC becomes BC2
Add C2C3 segment
CA has an intersection point (C3) -> CA becoes C3A

Just add a conditional function, that if only one intersection point is found (1st figure), you may add a point at segment extremity(between each extremity of segment where is intersection), and if 2 points, you have to remove C point from the list.(point that is present on each segment with intersection)